# Running OpenVPN on EC2 and DNS leak check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc, openvpn

I have installed an OpenVPN access server on an free tier EC2 instance with default VPC and connected to it. My ip is changed but when I checked dns leak using (https://www.dnsleaktest.com/), it is showing multiple EC2 server name(shown below).

```
     IP                          Hostname                               ISP          Country
3.18.181.28     ec2-3-18-181-28.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.    Amazon.com  Columbus, United States 
3.31.116.124    ec2-3-31-116-124.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.   Amazon.com  Columbus, United States 
3.18.128.150    ec2-3-18-128-150.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.   Amazon.com  Columbus, United States 
3.17.150.179    ec2-3-17-150-179.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.   Amazon.com  Columbus, United States
```

Can anyone explain me How/Why these server being called and can these server owner see my ip address?
And none of the above ip is my EC2 ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**because VPN connection will 'tunnel' your traffic through its own servers, masking your IP address, your location and activity.**

and It  shows your `ISP's (Internet Service Provider) IP`, Not your Ec2 Instance IP..

Those are not Ec2 Server IP.